# How to avoid making new connections in aiosqlite

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I was using `sqlite3` till now for my discord bot. In that case I could simply make a global variable of database connection and use it everywhere in the code.

```py
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("path/to/db")

def function():
  cur = conn.cursor()
  cur.execute(...)
```

But now in the case of `aiosqlite` I can't create  a global variable because `aiosqlite.connect()` is a coroutine and I can only use it inside an async function.

```py
import aiosqlite

async def function():
  conn = await aiosqlite.connect()
  ...
```

The problem is that I call that function often and making new connections over and over again, Is it a good practice? Won't it cause database issues? How can I store a connection and use it everywhere

Comment: are you subclassing the client or bot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to the database inside `on_ready` or `on_connect`.

```py
bot.db_con = None # In the global scope

def on_ready():
   if bot.db_con is None:
       bot.db_con = connect() #connect to db
```

Note: We're using `bot.db_con` so we can use the same connection inside cogs, if you don't have cogs, you can just use `db_con` instead of adding it as an attribute to bot.
bot is the `discord.Bot` or `discord.Client` instance.

Another note:
If you are subclassing `discord.Client` or `discord.Bot`, define db_con as None in the `__init__` and connect in on_ready.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run):

```
import asyncio

import aiosqlite


async def get_conn():
    conn = await aiosqlite.connect()
    return conn

async def function(conn):
    # Use conn object asynchronously
       

def main():
    conn = asyncio.run(get_conn())
    function(conn)
    # rest of the code
```

Unless you want to do multiple db operations simultaneously, there's no need for multiple connections.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to `conn.close()` after every database operation. The connection is then only open when I need it.

```
    conn = await aiosqlite.connect(database)
    c = await conn.cursor()
    await c.execute(whatever db operation)
    await conn.commit()
    await conn.close()
```